# OpenGL ES 3.1 app keeps flashing on ARM Mali GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es, mali

I have written a OpenGL ES 3.1 app for Android and I am battling with problems on one particular platform, ARM Mali GPU. The program appears to run correctly on Adreno and PowerVR GPUs.

One frame is composed of several render passes. The render passes communicate with help of a Shader Storage Buffer Object and atomic counters. The whole thing looks like this:

```
Pass1_Initialize_SSBO_and_Atomic();
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

Pass2_Fill_SSBO_With_initial_Data();
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   {
   Pass3_Render_Object(i);
   glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
   }

Pass4_Compose_Everything();
```

Now, the problem is that on Mali the screen keeps flashing. I have made many recordings and watched them frame-by-frame. What happens is that about 95% of frames look correct, but every so often an arbitrary subset of Objects disappears, and reappears in the next frame.

############################################

The problem is, I have no idea what can be causing the disappearing Objects. What I've tried so far is to keep removing code to see if the bug is still there - in an attempt to come up with the shortest piece of code that reproduces the problem. This approach fails because the more code I remove, the harder the bug gets to reproduce. Initially it keeps happening about twice per second, after several passes of removing various bits I can only reproduce it once per minute, and ultimately I cannot reproduce it anymore, but I have no idea if this is because I just removed the offending code or because I just passed some threshold and the bug is still there but is now very hard to reproduce.

The second thing I tried is to measure the bug by taking a look at the SSBO. I memory-map it to CPU at certain moments between passes and make sure it really does contain what it should.
Unfortunately as soon as I add a

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, mSSBO[0] );
glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, length, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
(...) // print the buffer
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

pretty much anywhere in the application code, the bug simply disappears.

In particular, when I remove the first glMemoryBarrier() and replace it with the above, the bug disappears completely ( I recorded 10 minutes worth of screen and watched this frame-by-frame, it's gone). This happens even if I don't inspect the buffer on CPU at all, I just map it and unmap it right away (which AFAIK should have the same effect like a memoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT) ??) This has raised a suspicion that maybe glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT) on Mali is buggy, so I wrote a test program to see - and this proved glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT) works just fine.

I also have a Mali Graphics Debugger and I can connect it to the phone, but when I do the bug immediately disappears. I stop tracing - it again starts flashing once-twice per second.

Would you have any advice how to approach such an issue?

**The code is GPL v2 and it is fully available to download** - is it 45k lines of Java, XML and GLSL though. If anybody wants to take a look, here it is:

 http://distorted.org/redmine/projects/distorted-android/wiki/How_to_compile_and_run_the_example_code 
(need to check out the 'order-independent-transparency' branch; master runs fine)

Comment: It sounds like you might be running out of memory and that your debug efforts are either: causing a synchronization that flushes all previous commands OR reducing the number of commands that fill up the memory and push the fault later and later into the runtime.  BTW, that link is bad.

Comment: Link corrected. How can I see if I am running out of memory? How can I measure it?

Comment: If the issue is running out of GPU memory, then how do you explain the fact that the bug disappears when I connect Mali Graphics Debugger and start tracing? And reappears again when I stop tracing? 100% repeatable.

Comment: The graphics debugger might be causing a synchronization. I'm thinking it might be a driver bug.  Is mapping/unmapping the buffer the only thing causing the bug to go away?  Have you tried a glFlush()?

Comment: I have asked this question in OpenGL.org forums ( https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/200754-Flashes-on-ARM-Mali?p=1291754#post1291754 ) and a 'OpenGL Guru' member over there says I am doing something that causes a 'full pipeline flush'. What do you think about this?

Comment: Can you throw a frame # on each frame rendered and see which frames are messed up?  A Continuous counter so you can tell if it's every 34 frames or so

Comment: But how do I detect programmatically that a given frame is missing Objects? I feel if I could do this, the bug would be gone... Oh wait, you are talking about marking all frames and then looking at the numbers when watching a recorded video... No, I am 100% sure this is not regular

Comment: "full pipeline flush" is what I have in mind when I say "synchronization that flushes all previous commands".

Comment: And yes, a 'glFlush()' makes the bug go away as well. Basically if you have the patience to read the thread in OpenGL.org forums, you'll see all the things I have already tried. Which is many...

Comment: Ok, yeah, sorry.  I went over as much code as I could.  I'm not convinced that this is not a driver bug: somehow the server is running out of memory by not reusing or freeing previous issued commands.  It may not be your fault at all.  If this were the case then you should be able to reliably reproduce this bug at a constant frequency.  Something like every ~Nth frame drops objects.  This would mean that maybe the server (or buffer commands) are backing up.

Comment: NO, sorry, I was wrong. glFlush() does NOT make the bug go away, surprisingly. I have just added a lot of them - one after each glMemoryBarrier(). WTF?

Comment: Yeah, ok, now I'm stumped. lol

Comment: Hmm, wait, I need to get my story straight. I've been debugging this for a week and I am sure glFlush() USED TO make this go away... Looks like I need to retest my claims.

Comment: So, there are now 20 glFlush()es all over the code, 1 after each major step - and it's flashing just the same. If I add just 1 'mapBufferRange - unmapBuffer' combo (synchronised!) at the beginning of my render loop, the flashing is completely gone.

Comment: Algorithm-wise this looks insanely expensive on a tile-based renderer - a full "all-bits" memory barrier after every draw call effectively causes the GPU to render each object as a unique render pass and round-trip the entire framebuffer via main memory.

Comment: Actually in production code I only use GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT, during debugging I changed it to ALL_BARRIER_BITS just to make sure I wasn't missing anything.